# How to include specific part of name at the end of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have made this question earlier today but I deleted it because I made a mistake and didn't provide all information. Sorry about that.
I use Regex and Linq to search all .txt files in a folder which match the pattern. That part of the code looks like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string file)
        {
            return File
                .ReadLines(file)
                .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
                .Where(match => match.Success)
                .Select(match => match.Value)
                .ToArray();
        }
```

Then write the matches in a .txt:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath, "*.txt");
var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => Search(file));
File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", extracts);
```

Is there anyway to write the name of the file where the match comes from? I have the names of the files in a string array.

```
var filenames = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt")
                .Select(filename => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename))
                .Select(filename => Regex.Match(filename, namePattern))
                .Where(match => match.Success)
                .Select(match => match.Value)
                .ToArray();
```

My goal "results.txt" example:

> Example1 **file1**
>
> Example2 **file2**
>
> Example3 **file3**

The "Examples" are the parts already working, the highlits are what I want to achieve somehow.

René Vogt kindly gave me an answer previously but after many tries I still couldn't solve the problem. His code is this:

```
var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => Search(file).Select(match => new {match, file}));
File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", 
                   extracts.Select(extract => extract.match + " " + extract.file));
```

It gives me a result like this:

> Example1 D:\~.txt1

Is there anyways I can use my namePattern to cut the unnecessary part of the text?

Thank you so much!

***Edit:*** Thanks for all the help so far! I'm trying all the answers right now. The *namePattern* is different from *pattern*. I use *pattern* to gain the important strings out of the texts and with *namePattern* I cut the unnecessary parts of the name. I can get the parts of the filename that I want, I'm struggling with the results text file. I can only write out the whole filename without the pattern or I fail everytime I try to include the pattern somehow.

```
static string namePattern = @"(\d{4})(?!.*\d)";
static string pattern = @"[A-Z]{1}\d{7}\s\d{1,5}";
```

Comment: Maybe you need `var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => $"{Search(file)} {System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}");`

Comment: You can use grouping in your regex pattern. What does your pattern look like now? I can't find it in your question.

Comment: @itsme86 I've updated the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the filename to be appended to each line

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string file)
{
    return File
        .ReadLines(file)
        .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
        .Where(match => match.Success)
        .Select(match => match.Value + " " + file)
        .ToArray();
}
```

If you want the filename to be appended a separate line

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string file)
{
    return (File
            .ReadLines(file)
            .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
            .Where(match => match.Success)
            .Select(match => match.Value)
           )
           .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(file, 1))
           .ToArray();
}
```

Since the methods returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, you can also drop the `ToArray()`. This results in the expression being evaluated lazily, i.e. when you are calling it in `File.WriteAllLines`. This can be an advantage if the files are very big or if you have many files, because the result will not be buffered. Each line read will immediately be written to the output.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Maybe I don't understand something but my output still looks like this: A1234567 1234 D:\~\Example.txt. Maybe i have a problem with the extracts? Because if I make a txt file out of filenames I get the right output.

Comment: Debug! What is the value of the `filename` parameter  in the `Search` method?

Comment: Sorry as I am a beginner I'm not sure if I understand what do you ask. The filename parameter is not included in the Search method. If I try to include it I get a "filenames" is not existing error. If I make a string array out of the filenames like jdweng suggested in my output there is "string[]" after every string instead of the desired part of the filename. Sorry if I misunderstood and thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I should have written `file` parameter. If you place a break point on the `return` line, you can see the value of the parameter by hovering over it once the code stops.

Comment: No problem. Yes, the value is the first txt file in the folder with full path if it matters.

Comment: simply by appending it, it won't get changed to "D:\~\Example.txt" if it wasn't before.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm doing my best to find where did I mess up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet of code. It will remove everything before the last backslash including the backslash itself

```
string filename = Regex.Match(filename, @".*\\([^\\]+$)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
             string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt")
                 .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x), namePattern))
                 .Select(x => string.Format("***{0}***", x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I can get the essential parts of the filename. I'm struggling with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using this method:

```
private string GetFileName(string file)
{
    return file.Split('\\').Last();
}
```

and then this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string file)
        {
            return File
                .ReadLines(file)
                .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
                .Where(match => match.Success)
                .Select(match => match.Value+" "+GetFileName(file))
                .ToArray();
        }
```

you will get what you want.

Or, directly this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string file)
        {
            return File
                .ReadLines(file)
                .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, pattern))
                .Where(match => match.Success)
                .Select(match => match.Value+" "+file.Split('\\').Last())
                .ToArray();
        }
```